# React Native Firebase - using "array-contains-any" on array of number elements fails when using IOS

Tags: swift, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

React Native Firebase to access Firestore database

**Database**
The field selectedJobTypesArr is an array of numbers. The elements are numbers because they come direct from a picklist

[image: database snippet]

**Operation**
.
I have a function that uses array-contains-any to match any value in selectedJobTypesArr

```
export const hasMatchingJobType = (user_id, jobTypeCodeArr) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let foundFlag = false;
    firestore()
      .collection('profiles')
      .where('user_id', '==', user_id)
      .where('selectedJobTypesArr', 'array-contains-any', jobTypeCodeArr)
      .orderBy('preferredName')
      .get()
      .then((value) => {
        value.docs.map((doc) => {
          foundFlag = true;
        });
        resolve(foundFlag);
      });
  });
};
```

To test it I call it as follows:

```
    const user_id = 'TUJawBQN9ge9qNl1l5Qi320UZXK2';
    const jobTypeCodeArr = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105];

    hasMatchingJobType(user_id, jobTypeCodeArr).then((res) => {
      console.log('res ', res);
    });
```

**Expected Behaviour**
returns true when called with matching data

**Actual Behaviour**
Returns false on IOS. If the database array elements are numbers, the array-contains-any only returns expected results with Android not IOS.
If I change the database elements to string, both android and IOS produce expected results.

**Environment**
React Native Firebase to access Firestore database
version @react-native-firebase/firestore@11.4.1

Android build.gradle:

```
 ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
}
```

IOS:
podfile containing directive
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '8.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

> `const jobTypeCodeArr = ['101', '102', '103', '104', '105'];`

This seems to be an array of `strings` but your Firestore document has an array of numbers which are not same. You must pass an array of numbers in `where()` to get your documents.

```
const user_id = 'TUJawBQN9ge9qNl1l5Qi320UZXK2';
const jobTypeCodeArr = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105];

hasMatchingJobType(user_id, jobTypeCodeArr).then((res) => {
  console.log('res ', res);
});
```

If you want to use the existing arrays which has numbers as strings then you would have to change the data type to string in Firestore as well.

Comment: Sorry, pasted wrong version of test data. It is indeed numbers